# Isekai manga/anime with a boy attending a magic academy

Tags: story-identification, manga, anime, magic, isekai

Need some help finding an anime/manga which i watched/read but i dont remember the name or source anymore. I will summarize the events which i remember from a certain episode. The anime was fantasy/isekai/magic.

- Entrance exam for a magic academy: The story begins with a young boy who takes an entrance exam for the prestigious Magic Academy
- Instructor attacks and takes MC as student: During the exam, MC is attacked by a powerful instructor at the academy. Instructor is impressed by MC's potential and takes him on as his student.
- Sword not good enough: Instructor tells MC that his sword isn't good enough for his skills and refers him to a swordsmith.
- Run-down shed: The swordsmith's workshop looks like a run-down shed, which is actually a front for his true workshop.
- Underground workshop: The swordsmith takes MC to his underground workshop, which is not known by many and caters primarily to nobles.
- Testing abilities: The swordsmith, who is actually a dwarf, asks MC to swing a sword of his choice with full strength to assess his abilities.
- Destroying part of the workshop: MC's swing is so powerful that it destroys a part of the workshop.

Looking forward to your responses!!

ps: the instructors sword was of green color and flexible it could grow in length and was forged of a special material. the instructor was a woman and after testing his abilities she declared that she would be taking mc as a student even before his admission to the academy was confirmed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read/watch this?

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you are confusing manga/anime with manhwa, and that you are talking about **[The Academy's
Genius Swordsman](https://www.webtoons.com/en/fantasy/the-academys-genius-swordsman/list?title_no=5752)**. The academy has departments for both magic and swordsmanship, and the main character is sent back in time to attend the academy in order to grow more and save the world from the disaster that happened before being sent back.

Other than starting at the academy, all the bullet points are fulfilled.

> Following a momentous battle against giants for the fate of the world, Ronan emerges victorious as the last man standing of the imperial army. As he laments this hollow victory with his dying commander, Grand Marshal Adeshan, they quickly learn that the war is far from over and an overwhelming force of giants descends from the heavens. Fearing the worst, yet seeing hope in the courageous Ronan, Adeshan uses her last time slip to send him back to the past, so that he can enroll in the prestigious Phileon Academy and become the strongest swordsman the empire has ever seen!